# Wow.js in React - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'getPropertyValue')

Tags: reactjs, animate.css, wow.js

I'm trying to get wow.js working in a new application, and I can't find an answer to the error I'm getting.
The strange thing is that I have already done it in other personal projects, and it has worked perfectly. The only difference I find compared to the other projects is that this time I initialized the installation with vite (although I don't think it has anything to do with it, I'll clarify it just in case)

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wECql.png)

Install: `npm install --save wowjs`

Dependency: `"wowjs": "^1.1.3"`

Index.html animate cdn:
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/4.1.1/animate.min.css"/>`

My import:

`import WOW from "wowjs";`

My initialization:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const newWOW = () => {new WOW.WOW({live: false}).init();}
    newWOW()
  }, []);
```

Label trying to call the animation

`<div className="homeSec__center wow animate__fadeIn" data-wow-duration="1.5s">`

Thank you in advance for trying to help me.

Comment: try use wow.js instead of wowjs. npm install --save wow.js . import WOW from "wow.js"

Comment: I love you :) it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use wow.js instead of wowjs.

`npm install --save wow.js`

`import WOW from "wow.js"`